# What is the need of convolution here?

Tags: qutip

This [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb) implements [GRAPE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780704003696)
for the synthesisizing a CNOT gate.
 More info can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kgrph09ghy5p74/khaneja2005GRAPE.pdf?dl=0) and in this short [presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huuhqwtvg1bx2ag/grape_june_2010_slides.pdf?dl=0).
In the following [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb) at In[8] [image: screenshot]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd1n9.png)
the starting guess for the control field is prepared as follows

- generate  a vector of random numbers for each control field
- convolve it with another vector of length 10 (consisting of '1').

Why is there a need to convolve the field? [GRAPE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780704003696) does not say anything about how one must generate the initial guess.
Also as side questions

- why do it with a vector of ones?
- what is the reason behind choosing the value 2*np.pi*0.01 in the initial random generation step